# Unit testing of a python based project using Jenkinsfile

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to do the unit test of a repository which is based on python. Here is the repo: https://github.com/Alok018/giskardpy/tree/noetic-devel
In jenkins, I have installed python and junit plugin.
This [Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/Alok018/giskardpy/blob/noetic-devel/Jenkinsfile) is using to build the repo inside the ros workspace. After creating an image, I want to test those [python](https://github.com/Alok018/giskardpy/tree/noetic-devel/test) examples.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to test those python scripts. But not able to do it. Bit confused about how to do it.